# RegEx named group with anchors and wildcard for characters captured

Tags: regex, powershell

Given a string of

```
$string = '* X64 Dynamo Core 1.3:  [DYN GUID !Uninstall (KEY MSIE PARAM)]|HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{F1AA809A-3D47-4FB9-8854-93E070C66A20}|'
```

I need to capture two named groups. Everything inside the `| |` at the end is a reference path, another key that relates to the one that produced this message. And everything before the `| |` is the message for this key. The `| |` is extraneous, and is only needed to demarcate the reference path. Ideally I would like to end up with

```
$result.Group.message > * X64 Dynamo Core 1.3:  [DYN GUID !Uninstall (KEY MSIE PARAM)]
```

and

```
$result.Group.referencePath > HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{F1AA809A-3D47-4FB9-8854-93E070C66A20}
```

I tried

```
[regex]$pattern = '(?<message>^*)(?<referencePath>|*|$)'
$pattern.Match($string)
```

and

```
[regex]$pattern = '^(?<message>*)(?<referencePath>{*})$'
```

and

```
[regex]$pattern = '^(?<message>*)|(?<referencePath>*)|$'
```

But all throw the error

```
Cannot convert value "^(?<message>*)(?<referencePath>{*})$" to type "System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex". Error: "parsing "^(?<message>*)(?<referencePath>{*})$" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing."
```

I think my issue is with the fact that I am capturing any character other than |, and not handling that correctly.

For context, strings like this are stored in an `[Ordered]` dictionary with the paths as the key. So I need to extract the message and the reference path, then find the index of the reference path, then delete the current key, and add a new key at the index of the reference +1, using just the message. So when I get a report of hundreds of Uninstall Keys being processed, the ones that got skipped (the data I am working with here) is listed directly below the related one that wasn't skipped, rather than potentially many lines away.

Comment: the main problem seem to be you're not escaping the pipe to match it literally. give this a try `(?<message>.+?)\|(?<referencePath>.+)(?=\|)` seem to work fine

Comment: Hmm, with no anchors? Perhaps I was focusing on the wrong issues. Now it seems my problem is accessing the data. `[regex]$pattern = '(?<message>.+?)\|(?<referencePath>.+)(?=\|)'
$test = $pattern.Match($string)` looks like I get the two named captures. But I thought `$test.Groups.message` would produce the right info. All the examples I see use some convoluted pipeline stuff. But I could have sworn there was a way to directly access a named group.

Comment: Aha, I can't use `.` notation, and I need to index twice. But `$test[0].Groups['message']` works! And it seems anchors are bit not what I expected, or at least the end anchor. But this works. `[regex]$pattern = '^(?<message>.+?)\|(?<referencePath>.+)(?=\|$)'`

Comment: If the string always starts with `*` you could use `'(?<message>^\*.+?)` I suppose (asterisk also has to be escaped!). And yes you can `$re = [regex] '(?<message>^\*.+?)\|(?<referencePath>.+)(?=\|)'` then `$re.Match($string).Groups['message']` and same for `referencePath`

Comment: A few things I need to dig into here. One question. I was confused by `(?=\|$)` and when I tried `(\|$)` it still works. So, what is that `?=` doing?

Comment: See Explanation here: https://regex101.com/r/hUUR4c/2

Comment: As for the first character, for now it's always *, but I can imagine needing to expand on that. And for the moment I have `^(?<message>.+?)\|(?<referencePath>.+)(\|$)` seeming to work on any first character.

Comment: You can also use `-match` with a normal string pattern (not a regex instance) and then the captured results are stored in `$matches`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're facing while instantiating a new [`Regex` instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-7.0) are all due to [un-escaped quantifier `*`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.2#quantifiers):

> The asterisk (`*`) matches the previous element zero or more times.

There are no previous elements on all appearances of it on all your regexes and you clearly wanted to match a literal asterisk (`\*`) instead of using a quantifier.

As for the regex that could work but clearly needs improvement:

```
$re    = [regex] '(?<message>^\*.+?)\|(?<referencePath>.+)(?=\|)'
$match = $re.Match($string)
$match.Groups['message'].Value       # => * X64 Dynamo Core 1.3:  [DYN GUID !Uni....
$match.Groups['referencePath'].Value # => HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Win...
```

The [`-match` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#matching-operators) can also work fine without the need of instantiating a `Regex` instance. The captured results are stored in the [automatic variable `$Matches`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#matches):

```
$re = '(?<message>^\*.+?)\|(?<referencePath>.+)(?=\|)'
if($string -match $re) {
    $Matches['message']       # => * X64 Dynamo Core 1.3:  [DYN GUID !Uni....
    $Matches['referencePath'] # => HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Win...
}
```